# Почему скрипт не работает в IE и Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari

Есть сайт который работает на chrome, mozilla, opera. А в IE и safari выдает ошибку в этом файле

**jquery-1.10.2.min.js**

```
...
globalEval: function(t) 
{
  t && x.trim(t) && (e.execScript || function(t) 
  {
    e.eval.call(e, t)  // строка 192
  })(t)
},
...
```

IE

> SCRIPT1003: Предполагается наличие ':'
>
> Файл: jquery-1.10.2.min.js, строка: 192, столбец: 9

safari

> jquery-1.10.2.min.js:192 SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found
>   '(' instead

**UPD**
Попробовал заменить jquery-1.10.2.min.js на jquery-3.3.1.js

safari

```
// Replace/restore the type attribute of script elements for safe DOM manipulation
function disableScript( elem ) {
    elem.type = ( elem.getAttribute( "type" ) !== null ) + "/" + elem.type; // строка 5622
    return elem;
}
```

> jquery-3.3.1.js:5622 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
>   (evaluating 'elem.getAttribute( "type" )')

**UPD** В globalEval в параметре t передается такой скрипт

```
View
(
    "TotalsInfoView",
    {},
    (
        function()
        {
            var p =
            {
                init: function(config)
                {
                    this._config = config;
                    this._super("totalsInfoView");
                    this._total1Label = new TextView("textField totalLabel", config.total1Label, 0, 4);
                    this._total2Label = new TextView("textField totalLabel", config.total2Label, 0, 4);
                    this._total10 = new MTextView("textField total0", 0, 4, "totalCur", 100000);
                    this._total20 = new MTextView("textField total0", 0, 4, "totalCur", 100000);
                    this.addChild(this._total1Label);
                    this.addChild(this._total10);
                    this.addChild(this._total2Label);
                    this.addChild(this._total20);
                    this._total10.curType(config.curType);
                    this._total10.noCo(config.noCo);
                    this._total20.curType(config.curType);
                    this._total20.noCo(config.noCo);
                    this.setZIndex(111);
                    positionFields.call(this);
                },
                updateTotal1(value) 
                {
                    this._total10.mValue(value);
                    positionFields.call(this);
                },
                updateTotal2(value) {
                    this._total20.mValue(value);
                    positionFields.call(this);
                }
            };
            function positionFields()
            {
                var self = this;
                setTimeout
                (
                    function () 
                    {
                        self._total1Label.x(118);
                        self._total10.setPosition(self._total1Label.x() + self._total1Label.getWidth() + 10, 4);
                        self._total2Label.x(self._total10.x() + self._total10.getWidth() + 30);
                        self._total20.setPosition(self._total2Label.x() + self._total2Label.getWidth() + 10, 4);
                    },
                    0
                );

            }
            return p;
        }
    )
    ()
);
```

**UPD** Весь функционал еще не заработал но в этой точке ошибки уже нет, после исправления updateTotal1(value) на updateTotal1: function(value) аналогично и updateTotal2

Comment: Очевидно, проблема не в самом jquery, а в других скриптах, которые обращаются к этому jquery и пихают в него какой-то хлам (или, точнее, то, что IE и Safari почему-то сочли хламом). Покопайтесь в вашем сайте и составьте [mcve], иначе помочь не получится

Comment: @andreymal пытаюсь. Вы не подскажете, как отловить код который вызывает эти функции?

Comment: e.eval.call(e, t)  // строка 192 Здесь e - это ссылка на объект window?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 самый банальный способ — отключать все ваши скрипты (или отдельные функции внутри скрипта) до тех пор, пока ошибка не пропадёт. Когда после очередного отключения ошибка пропала — значит ошибка где-то в последнем отключенном скрипте :) Ну а вообще браузер по-хорошему должен бы рядом с ошибкой вывести стек, из которого можно было бы выяснить, кто именно обратился к jquery (а ещё в браузерах бывают отладчики)

Comment: @andreymal в переменной t хранится скрипт, видимо который должен выполниться командой `eval.call` может я его выложу, я ошибок не вижу

Comment: @andreymal добавил код. Скорее всего в нем синтаксическая ошибка которую хром пропускает, а сафари нет.

Comment: IE не умеет в свойства/методы в литерале объекта, поэтому падает на строках `updateTotal1(value)` и подобных, надо просто переписать, как метод выше `updateTotal1: function(value)`

Answer (score -1):

Я предлагаю сбойную функцию изложить в следующей редакции:

```
/ Replace/restore the type attribute of script elements for safe DOM manipulation
function disableScript( elem ) {
if(elem.nodeType == undefined)
  return;
if(elem.nodeType != 1)
  return;
elem.type = ( elem.getAttribute( "type" ) !== null ) + "/" + elem.type;
return elem;
}
```